# What is a subtraction function that is similar to sum() for subtracting items in list?

Tags: python, function, sum, subtraction

I am trying to create a calculator, but I am having trouble writing a function that will subtract numbers from a list.
For example:

```
class Calculator(object):
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.args = args

    def subtract_numbers(self, *args):
        return ***here is where I need the subtraction function to be****
```

For addition, I can simply use return `sum(args)` to calculate the total but I am unsure of what I can do for subtractions.

Comment: How would you define a "`subtract`" function? For sum, it's intuitive. You just add all the numbers. But for subtraction, what are you subtracting from and what are you subtracting?

Comment: You first need to define what subtraction function is for multiple arguments. is it `first_element - sum(rest_of_elements)`? Is it `sum(args[i] * (-1)^1`? is it `abs(max(list) - sum(rest_of_elements))`? As you can see, there are endless number of possibilities - what *exactly* are you after?

Comment: How exactly is it supposed to work? You want to subtract those numbers in the list from what?

Answer (score 21):

```
from functools import reduce  # omit on Python 2
import operator

a = [1,2,3,4]

xsum = reduce(operator.__add__, a)  # or operator.add
xdif = reduce(operator.__sub__, a)  # or operator.sub

print(xsum, xdif)
## 10 -8
```

`reduce(operator.xxx, list)` basically "inserts" the operator in-between list elements.

Comment: Is there a reason why you prefer the underscores version of the operator names?

Comment: @Marcin: none, except the underscores are sexy ;))

Answer (score 7):

It depends exactly what you mean. You could simply subtract the sum of the rest of the numbers from the first one, like this:

```
def diffr(items):
    return items[0] - sum(items[1:])
```

It's tough to tell because in subtraction it's dependent on the order in which you subtract; however if you subtract from left to right, as in the standard order of operations:

> x0 - x1 - x2 - x3 - ... - xn = x0 - (x1 + x2 + x3 + ... + xn)

which is the same interpretation as the code snippet defining `diffr()` above.

It seems like maybe in the context of your calculator, `x0` might be your *running total*, while the `args` parameter might represent the numbers `x1` through `xn`. In that case you'd simply subtract `sum(args)` from your running total. Maybe I'm reading too much into your code... I think you get it, huh?

Answer (score 0):

Subtract function is same as sum having negative signs like this

```
x = 1
y = 2
sum([x, y])

>>> 3

sum([x, -y])

>>> -1
```

for more numbers

```
a = 5
b = 10
c = 15
sum([a, b, c])
sum([a, -b, -c])
```

In general,
Subtract function is formed by changing you list signs like this

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, ...., n]
new_l = l[0] + [-x for x in l[1:]

# Or
new_l = [-x for x in l]
new_l[0] = -newl[0]

# Or one liner,
new_l = [-x for x in l if x != l[0]]
```